# Is there a way to stretch parent div or not?

Tags: html, css

My question is not so specific so I could ask it without example, so here is my case: let's say I have a list of books, that I display inside of parent div, that has dimensions. List might be larger than parent div or not, but if so, there are scrollbars. Book has it's title and some optional specs with server-side defined widths.

What I need is, that book specs would stretch inner container, but the title would not, being cut with ellipsis.

I could only do it with some js, feels lame, so please, is there a way to make it with css only?

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="book">
      <div class="title">The Persecution and Assassination of Jean-Paul Marat as Performed by the Inmates of the Asylum of Charenton Under the Direction of the Marquis de Sade</div>
      <div class="attrs">
        <div class="item" style="width:200px">Author: Peter Weiss</div>
        <div class="item" style="width:200px">Rating: 4.03</div>
        <div class="item" style="width:300px">Published December 1st 2001 by Waveland Pr Inc (first published 1963)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="book">
      <div class="title">1984</div>
      <div class="attrs">
        <div class="item" style="width:200px">Author: George Orwell</div>
        <div class="item" style="width:200px">Rating: 4.15</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the pen to illustrate: https://codepen.io/Masquer/pen/rdwJzQ

Comment: In your specific example, all you need to do is calculate what the width of the #inner container is - in this case, 200px + 200px + 300px, and add some `white-space:nowrap`s in the right places. Then you're done. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gexxeJ Or would that be cheating?

Comment: Well, yes, because all book specs are optional and their widths are set inline server-side.

Comment: If the widths are known at the server side, then you can also change the width of the container server-side, right?

Comment: Yes, I can, of course. But its even uglier than current implementation with js, because I'd have to take into account all paddings and margins and icons if there are any. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is much simpler than your code indicates, but it's as follows:
The width of the #inner container should be determined by its contents (not counting the title), and the title is only as wide as the container. No matter the width of the contents. That's it.

So the solution is simple: don't let the title count for the width. In other words, give the title `position: absolute`.

```css
#inner {
  background:#bbb;
  display:inline-block;
}

.title {
  background:#ddd;
  height:30px; margin:1em;
  position:relative;
}

.title > span {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%; line-height:30px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.contents {
  background:#ddd;
  margin:1em;
}
.contents img {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">
 <div class="title">
  <span>A very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long title</span>
 </div>
 <div class="contents">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x100" alt="400x100">
 </div>
</div>
```

In this example I never set widths in pixels anywhere, so it's as wide as the picture inside, ignoring the width of the title. (You can use a different picture, or a text, and it will adjust to the new width.)

It took me a while to hit upon the solution, but the structure of your example pushed me in the wrong direction at first. Sorry. For example, the #outer container isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem. You can put an outer container around this code if you want.

Comment: Many thanks, I've just tried that to my markup and it works like a charm! Pure css. The only question is how could I missed that idea myself, looks so obvious now, when its solved :)

Answer (score 0):

IF you use white-space: nowrap; it will do your work.

```
 .title {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you need "..."  on end you need to describe max-width of that line so overflow will be ellipsis.

```
.title {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width:800px;

}
```

Comment: Nope, sorry, outer container should remain as is.

Comment: ah ok. so what exactly do you need to achieve ?

Comment: The same behavior as in codepen, but without any js :)

Comment: Have you tried that yourself? :) Its not, it makes title to stretch inner container all the way.

Comment: yes because max width wasn't set up. i give you another example in my answer.  There is something else i can do for you?:D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167457/discussion-between-masquer-and-piotr-mirosz).

Comment: but only in that way your text will be overflow , otherwise it will not. There is no other way to do it with css. And you have max width in that case you give me it will be 770. You set all children width and text inside them overflow so main div (container) stay as it is. Try 770 to line it up.